# Нужно получить список все дубликатов в базе данных postgresql?

Tags: postgresql

Есть таблица с 40+ полями. Нужно найти все записи с одинаковыми значениями всех полей кроме поля id так как он уникален. Как составить запрос в котором не надо перечислять все поля?

Comment: Дубликатов, в которых одинаковы **все** поля? То есть, первичного ключа в таблице нет?

Comment: Есть, в это и всё дело.

Comment: Это невозможно. Значит, у вас в таблице нет строк, в которых совпадают **все** значения.

Comment: За пренебрежение нормализацией всегда приходится платить, тем или иным способом.

Comment: Я новичок, можно поподробней?

Answer (score 1):

```
select
  (some_table.*)::text,
  count(*)
from some_table
group by some_table.*
having count(*) > 1;
```